# Matlab FIR Filter

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have to analyse the coefficients for a Finite Impulse Response (FIR)  filter for minimal word lengths so there should be no internal overflows that impact to the output.

> `-0.0041    0.0077    0.0893       0.3276         0.0893    0.0077  -0.0041`

I have tried

```
f = fdesign.bandpass(0.0041,0.0077,0.0893,0.3276, 0.0893, 0.0077,0.0041);
Hd = design(f, 'equiripple');
fvtool(Hd)
```

I get the following error:

> Frequency specifications must be between 0 and 1.

Then I calculated Scale factor and multiplied all coefficients

```
coefficients  h[0] +  h[1] +  h[2] +…+  h[M] = S

Log base 2 (S )+ 1
```

but still I am getting the same error:

> Frequency specifications must be between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`fdesign.bandpass`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/fdesign.bandpass.html) can be used to design bandpass filter from filter specifications including parameters such as:

- frequency at the edge of the start of the first stop band
- frequency at the edge of the start and end of the passband
- frequency at the edge of the start of the second stop band
- attenuation in the stop bands
- amount of ripple allowed in the pass band
- filter order

What you have appears to be filter coefficients rather than filter specifications based on the parameters above. To create a filter object with these coefficients, you may use one of many available structure options from [`dfilt`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/dfilt.html). In your case an appropriate structure for a FIR filter would be `dfilt.dffir`:

```
b = [-0.0041,0.0077,0.0893,0.3276, 0.0893, 0.0077,-0.0041];
Hd = dfilt.dffir(b);
fvtool(Hd)
```